# Testing Mock Locations not Working

Tags: android, unit-testing, location

```
I have written a simple Gps Service. Now I am writing a testcase for testing it. I am trying to send a mock location but the onLocation changed is not getting called in my GpsService location listener.

Here is my GpsService








/**
* returns the binder object that client of this can bind to
*/
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e("GpsService","StartService");


}

private class MyLocationListener implements  LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        Log.e("GpsService","Location in GpsService"+loc.toString());
        if(loc.hasAccuracy() && loc.getAccuracy() <= minAccuracyMeters)
        {
            if(targetLocation != null)
            {
                float distance = loc.distanceTo(targetLocation);
                Log.e("GpsService ","Location latitude +"+loc.getLatitude()+"longitude "+loc.getLongitude());
                if(distance < 5.0)
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have reached the target location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

    }

public void setTargetLocation (Location _location){
    targetLocation = _location;
}


/**
 * Class for clients to access. Because we know this service always runs in
 * the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        GpsService getService() {
                return GpsService.this;
        }
}

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(lm != null)
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    super.onDestroy();
}

//Setting up for test case
public void setUpProvider(String provider){

    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 
                    minTimeMillis, 
                    minDistanceMeters,
                    locationListener);

}

Now here is my TestCase
```

public class MockLocationTest extends ServiceTestCase {

```
private LocationManager locationManager = null;
private static final String MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER = "MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER";
private List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

public MockLocationTest(Class<GpsService> serviceClass) {
    super(serviceClass);

}

public MockLocationTest() {
    super(GpsService.class);

}


 @Override
    protected void setupService() {

        super.setupService();
        System.out.println("Service Set Up");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),GpsService.class);
        startService(intent);
        assertNotNull("The Service should not be null",getService());
        System.out.println("Service Started");
    }


    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();



    }



    @MediumTest
    public void testBindable() {

        Intent startIntent = new Intent();
        startIntent.setClass(getContext(), GpsService.class);
        IBinder service =  bindService(startIntent);
        assertNotNull("Bound to service ",service);
        getService().setUpProvider(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER);

        Location demo = new Location(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER);
        demo.setLatitude(22.579937);
        demo.setLongitude(88.486805);
        getService().setTargetLocation(demo);

        System.out.println("Test Bindable");
    }






    @SmallTest
    public void testMockData(){
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService((Context.LOCATION_SERVICE));

        locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER, true);
        Location location = new Location(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER);
        location.setLatitude(22.579937);
        location.setLongitude(88.486805);

        location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // show debug message in log


        // provide the new location

        locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER, location);//send mock data


    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {

        super.tearDown();
    }
```

}

Unfortunately I cant see any log in the onLocationChange callback in the service. The testcase runs successfully.
 I have added the following in both my service and testservice's manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>

Can anybody help me here
```

I also tried putting this in one function

@LargeTest
        public void testBindable() {

```
        Intent startIntent = new Intent();
        startIntent.setClass(getContext(), GpsService.class);
        IBinder service =  bindService(startIntent);
        assertNotNull("Bound to service ",service);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.addTestProvider(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER, false, false,
                false, false, false, false, false, 0, 5);
        locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER, true);
        getService().setUpProvider(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER,locationManager);


        Location demo = new Location(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER);
        demo.setLatitude(22.579937);
        demo.setLongitude(88.486805);
        demo.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        getService().setTargetLocation(demo);

        Location narkeldanga = new Location(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER);
        narkeldanga.setLatitude(22.578986);
        narkeldanga.setLongitude(88.470154);
        narkeldanga.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());



        locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER, narkeldanga);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);

            // gracefully handle Thread interruption (important!)
            if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                throw new InterruptedException("");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

        locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER, demo);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);

            // gracefully handle Thread interruption (important!)
            if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                throw new InterruptedException("");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

        System.out.println("Test Bindable");
    }
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I and others have encountered in jUnit tests.  Namely, testBindable() will run in one thread while your service is running in another.  The result is that the location service is still setting up and hasn't even thought about using your callbacks when the test hits the end and jUnit clears everything from memory.  I am still looking for a good recipe to follow for structuring such a test, but I can suggest a few things you could try.  The simplest is just to put a sleep() in your test to give things time to process in the other threads.  For example:

```
public void testBindable() throws Exception {

    Intent startIntent = new Intent();
    startIntent.setClass(getContext(), GpsService.class);
    IBinder service =  bindService(startIntent);
    assertNotNull("Bound to service ",service);
    getService().setUpProvider(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER);

    Location demo = new Location(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER);
    demo.setLatitude(22.579937);
    demo.setLongitude(88.486805);
    getService().setTargetLocation(demo);

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

    System.out.println("Test Bindable");
}
```

This approach is not ideal for a number of reasons.  5 seconds (or whatever you put in) may not be enough sometimes or too much time in other cases.

Alternatively, you can use latches or other mechanisms to detect when your callbacks have executed.  However, that approach complicates your code with latches (or you can use mutex locks) that are only used by the test and ideally should not be part of the actual application under test.

Answer (score 0):

The value of MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER shouldn't be "flp" ?

http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html#TestData